# Jquery: How to put a listener on Angular strap datetimepicker value change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-strap

I have to listen to the angular strap date time picker value change from `jquery`

*(Cannot add code in the angular application/controllers or use anuglar code)*.

Please provide a way to do it by using Jquery/JScript only. Many thanks

[AngularStrap DatetimePicker Documentation](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers)

**What I tried**

```
$("#datepk").bind('input', function(){alert('value changed');})

$("#datepk").bind('change', function(){alert('value changed');})

$("#datepk").bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){alert('value changed');})
```

Above methods are not working. Also, one more thing is `val()` function is returning the value but when I am trying to get the value from `.attr('value')` then it's `undefined`.

```
$("#datepk").val(); /// nicely retruning the value
$("#datepk").attr('value'); /// returning undefined
```

**dummy application**

```html
<htm>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.8/angular-strap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.8/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script>
      var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
      myapp.config(function($datepickerProvider) {
        angular.extend($datepickerProvider.defaults, {
          dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
          startWeek: 1
        })
      });

      myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$datepicker',
        function($scope, $datepicker) {
          $scope.selectedDate = "2016-04-28T09:57:58.274Z"; // <- [object Date]
          $scope.selectedDateAsNumber = 509414400000; // <- [object Number]
          $scope.fromDate = "2016-04-08T18:30:00.000Z"; // <- [object Date]
          $scope.untilDate = ''; // <- [object Undefined]
        }
      ]);
    </script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <form name="datepickerForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
      <!-- Basic example -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': datepickerForm.date.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date <small>(as date)</small>
        </label>
        <input id="datepk" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" bs-datepicker>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</htm>
```

Comment: Is it safe to say you have a typo in the question between `<input id="datepk".../>` and your jQuery binding `$("#datepkr")` (the extra r), but not in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you call JavaScript function whenever date changed.

```js
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ngAnimate', 'mgcrea.ngStrap']);
  myapp.config(function($datepickerProvider) {
    angular.extend($datepickerProvider.defaults, {
      dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
      startWeek: 1
    })
  });

  myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$datepicker',
    function($scope, $datepicker) {
      $scope.selectedDate = "2016-04-28T09:57:58.274Z"; // <- [object Date]
      $scope.selectedDateAsNumber = 509414400000; // <- [object Number]
      $scope.fromDate = "2016-04-08T18:30:00.000Z"; // <- [object Date]
      $scope.untilDate = ''; // <- [object Undefined]

    }
  ]);


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepk").on("click", function() {
      $(".datepicker table tr td").on("click tap", function(event) {
        alert($("#datepk").val())
      })
    })
  })
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.8/angular-strap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-strap/2.3.8/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
    <form name="datepickerForm" class="form-inline" role="form">
      <!-- Basic example -->
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': datepickerForm.date.$invalid}">
        <label class="control-label"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Date <small>(as date)</small>
        </label>
        <input id="datepk" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" bs-datepicker>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can not edit controller due to some reasons because of the task I am on. I have to do it with jquery or java script. many thanks for your suggestion. Also, my task is to create a generic functionality that does some task whenever any date time picker changes its value. I hope you understand

Comment: See updated answer. Hope this will solve your problem. Here is working Plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/6V7GOqmkzA8nFmFuGSqa?p=preview

Comment: Itis cool but not working every time. Suppose I select a date then change it then the alert is not getting called.

Comment: You are trying to change using keyboard? Add keyboard events for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below points will help you.

Add `ng-change` to your input.

```
<input id="datepk" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" bs-datepicker ng-change="myChange()">
```

and in your controller add:

```
$scope.myChange= function(){
      console.log($scope.selectedDate);
};
```

`ng-change` will call `myChange` every time when the value changes.

Comment: As I have mentioned in question that I have to do it by using Jquery only and I can not use angular
.